# Pack every dependency in a visual studio project to send easily

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dependencies, project

So I have faced a problem several times where I'm working in a big C++ project with several dependencies and I need to send the project to some friend so he can take a look at it and debug it.

Is there any way to pack the whole project including every dependencies that the project is using (boost, python...) so the person who get it doesn't have to loose the time downloading the dependencies and setting up paths to libs and so on??

Cheers

Comment: You could build a folder hierarchy for the project where you have all necessary libraries and dependecies within an "Import" folder. Within your project refer to this location based on the folder your project is stored, i.e: "../../Import". If this works for you I could elaborate it in an answer.

Comment: if my answer worked for you, will you be kind enough to mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is to build a Solution folder that has everything that I need. When a coworker needs to continue coding for that solution he simply copies the whole "Solution" folder and runs the .sln with VisualStudio.

Be **warned** that this Solution folder is usually very big, since it contains everything needed to compile and run the projects.

Then you configure each project to fetch the dependencies relatively to where the .proj file is:

[image]

[image]

And the folder structure for the above images would be:

[image]