# Include from directory C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to run this code

http://dlib.net/dlib/statistics/cca.h.html

As you can notice, it contains many include, which I copy them.
But inside each include there are a lot of includes like this :

```
#include "../matrix.h"
```

It contains

```
#include "matrix/matrix.h"
#include "matrix/matrix_utilities.h"
#include "matrix/matrix_subexp.h"
#include "matrix/matrix_math_functions.h"
#include "matrix/matrix_assign.h"
#include "matrix/matrix_la.h"
#include "matrix/symmetric_matrix_cache.h"
#include "matrix/matrix_conv.h"
#include "matrix/matrix_read_from_istream.h"
#include "matrix/matrix_fft.h"
#include "matrix/matrix_generic_image.h"
```

Is there any method to just include the main class? For example give the directory or the link of the classes?

Comment: yes. It depends on your compiler.What compiler do you use to compile your program?

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 @fnc12

Comment: create a new header file and add all includes in it. Then instead of bunch of includes include only this header.

Comment: Do I have to copy the content of each header file? since the include statement only gives error @fnc12

Comment: What do you mean by "just include the main class"? There is no correspondence between classes and files in C++.

Comment: Could you clarify the question? I understand that at the moment you are including many files, because they are included in `matrix.h`, but you only want to include specific files. Which files do you want to include?

Comment: No, copying the content is rarely a good idea. You might instead want to create (or use if already exists) a cumulative header file containing just #include statements for individual headers which you always need. In C++ projects generated in Visual Studio, the StdAfx.h is often used for such purposes. If you create your own header file, don't forget a #pragma once at the top of it, to avoid unintended multiple inclusion.

Comment: @molbdnilo What I meant, can I include just the matrix.h and all the inside includes will be included automatically

Comment: @H.Y `#include "header.h"` means "replace this line with the contents of the file 'header.h'". If that file contains further includes, the process repeats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet the problem lies with your include directories.

I assume you downloaded the full zip file from http://dlib.net/ (latest version seems to be 18.18). Inside that .zip you have a bunch of folders: examples, tools, dlib. In **dlib** folder you have all the header files.

You should add the path to wherever you extracted the .zip contents to the "Additional Include Directories" property of your project:

[image]

Then just use dlib in your own code as showed in the examples, for instance *3d_point_cloud_ex.cpp*:

```
#include <dlib/gui_widgets.h>
#include <dlib/image_transforms.h>
```

Initially there is no need to create extra header files, all seems to be provided with a nice folder structure. I encourage you to read dlib's documentation before start using it.

You might also want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34910578/5583153) to another question to help you build a handy project folder structure.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was my problem @Nacho

Comment: @H.Y, glad I could help! Cheers